# How can a Flutter Cubit emit multiple state changes

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc, cubit

I have a Cubit that retrieves json data from an API.  It processes the data and based on the processing, will need to change the state of multiple widgets.

Essentially, using some if statements, the state changes will need to be emitted if the data matches certain criterion.

This code sample shows the idea, but I'm not sure how to actually fulfill the need within the if statements.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class ProcessingCubit extends Cubit<String> {
  
  ProcessingCubit() : super("");

  void getDataFromAPI() async {
    Response response;
    var dio = Dio();
    response = await dio.get(
        'http://our.internalserver.com:8080/api/getdata.php',
        queryParameters: {});
    var parsedjsonresponse = json.decode(response.data.toString());
    //the json returned is an array of objects.  For this code example, 
    //we're only going through slot 0 of the array of objects
    if (!parsedjsonresponse['ourdata'].isEmpty) {
      print(parsedjsonresponse['ourdata']);
    }
    if (!parsedjsonresponse['ourdata'][0]['code'] == "001") {
      //emit state for this code, so that the necessary widget  
      //will show something
    }
    if (!parsedjsonresponse['ourdata'][0]['code'] == "002") {
      //emit state for this code, so that the necessary widget will
      //show something (different widget than the "if" block above
    }
    if (!parsedjsonresponse['ourdata'][0]['alert'] == "1") {
      //emit state for this alert so that the alert widget
      //will show something
    }
  }
}
```

Sometimes none of the if statements will need to change state, sometimes all may need to, and sometimes only some.

Answer (score 0):

You can emit states using:

`emit(CubitState);`

Since you declared your Cubit State to be a String it would be:

`emit("apiResponseAsString");`

You can emit as much states as you want. So for each of your ifs you can emit the according string.

The [official documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttercountertutorial?id=counter-cubit) for the bloc library gives you great examples for cubits.

Comment: If this Cubit emits multiple states as string, how would each BlocBuilder that will receive one of the strings that is emitted know which string it is receiving?  In other words, how does each BlocBuilder get the correct string from the Cubit?